# Typescript isn't complaining when a React Functional Component (React.FC<Props>) with wrong props is send as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to send a functional component with some props to another component and in the receiving component trying to type check that component for some of the props. Here is the code:

```js
// BaseButton.tsx

export type ButtonProps = {
  label: string
  size?: 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'normal'
  icon?: React.FC<{ size?: number; foo: string }>
} & React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement

export const BaseButton: React.FC<ButtonProps> = props => {/* ...return the button component */}
```

```js
// Icon.tsx

type Props = {
  style?: React.CSSProperties
  size?: number
}

export const Icon: React.FC<Props> = ({ style, size = 24 }) => {/* ... return Icon component */}
```

```js
// where I render the component

<BaseButton icon={Icon} label="Sign in" />
//                ^^^ I am expecting Typescript to complain
```

Since the `icon?: React.FC<{ size?: number; foo: string }>` in `ButtonProps` has an extra prop `foo` I am expecting Typescript to complain about it. But it is not.

### EDIT:

This will throw an error while trying to invoke it with JSX syntax:

```
icon?: React.FC<{ size?: number; foo: string }>
```

```
const {icon: Icon} = props
<Icon />
```

Instead, the type should be:

`icon?: React.ComponentType<{ bar: number }>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can assign [functions with fewer parameters to functions with more parameters](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters):

```
let fn1 = (props: { size: number }) => 42
let fn2 = (props: { size: number; foo: string }) => 42

fn2 = fn1  // this works
fn1 = fn2 // error
```

Or in other words:

With a variable `let fn2` and type `(props: { size: number; foo: string }) => number` given, a client needs to call it with two props `size` and `foo`. We now can assign `fn2 = fn1`, as it is OK for the underlying implementation `fn1` to ignore some of the input props and only deal with `size`.

Carried over to your case:

`Icon` with type `React.FC<{ style?: React.CSSProperties; size?: number}>` is assignable to the `ButtonProps` icon property with type `React.FC<{ size?: number; foo: string }>`.

```
let fc1: React.FC<{
  style?: React.CSSProperties
  size?: number
}> = // ...
let fc2: React.FC<{ size?: number; foo: string }> = // ...

fc2 = fc1 // works
fc1 = fc2 // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC%20cAZlBCHAORSoYsCwAULwDZJ4dAHYBGOAF44ACjCMwhAFy44hYAC8kKkfhAAjJFBoBKKQD44AFgBMAofRE2ps%20REUq86rTr2GoANz0EBAqhDBQwCIA5qYW1nZ8PKLO0qIScAD0mXAwABbAhHAA7tAA1oS86S4pWTn5hXAiEDC8bTwAJkho-CjscILCaGIqyOgwAHQAYgDCADw4vHBqMACeggD8oxyTMyQkAAoKRjDASJU8y95IW01%20RrzU5rxdPX1Ug-RoNtvj0-NeTQ3XwGIxBOghMIRKKxJ7tOjfGrDKrDJGJIA)

Comment: Oh yea, the excess property thing. Yes, now I see what is the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The type `FunctionComponent` has function type definition, so you can pass either a React component or a function to be invoked later.

```
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null; <--- Here
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

Here's a sandbox with an example of invoking the `props.icon` component from the BaseButton component.  You'll see how the props `foo` and `size` must be passed when calling the function on line 21.

https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-banach-prwos?file=/src/App.tsx

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types